# Targetting spells at illusions

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

How would things resolve when targeting a spell, like magic missile, at an illusory creature?

For spells like Fireball, Lightning Bolt, etc. I think it's fairly clear the caster fires the spell off at the location they *think* there's a creature in, and it's up to the person controlling the illusion to decide how it reacts. Those spells don't need to be aimed at a creature at all, so the fact there isn't one there is irrelevant.

I'm asking about *magic missile* in particular because there's no attack roll required, and it automatically hits whatever it's aimed at. In fact WotC have confirmed [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/709541359422582784?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) that it bypasses mirror image for that reason - no attack roll, it hits the creature you aimed it at. But what if you're aiming at a creature that doesn't exist at all?

Does the spell fizzle and fail to have any effect at all - since you haven't targeted it correctly? Does it fire off and seem to hit the illusion? That seems wrong to me, since you can't normally make a magic missile hit non-creature targets.

RAW seems to suggest that the spell would fail because you hadn't targeted it correctly - which means it's a great way to reveal illusions. But is there anything that suggests otherwise?

This is a similar question to the linked one, but I'm not asking only about Magic Missile. The question is broader, and is about any/all spells that are required to be targeted at a 'creature' or similar, where an illusion wouldn't fulfill that requirement, or indeed any other condition that led a caster to believe a valid target was present for a spell, when that wasn't the case.

Other examples include Healing Word, Polymorph, and so on. Is the caster *aware* that the spell has failed? I note the answer on the [linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78016/does-magic-missile-hit-silent-images-illusory-creature) suggests two possibilities - either the spell goes off, or the caster fails to target the illusion - which I suppose *suggests* there's no official ruling addressing this.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE!  Please take the [tour] and have a look through the [help] to see how our Q&A site works.  I think your question is covered in the Q&A that Purple Monkey linked to.  Please review that; if your question is different, please edit the question to make sure that the difference is clear.  Happy Gaming!

Comment: This is a more general question than about magic missile. It is clear what he is asking in the first sentance. The answer to magic missile hitting a silent missile doesn't cover what this guy is asking. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: To the extent that the other question is answered correctly, it's generalizable to all the situations this question is asking about. This is a dupe.