# What happens if you cast magic missile at an illusion?

Tags: dnd-5e

From a comment on one of my answers: "An illusion isn't a creature so Magic Missile can't target it. RAW doesn't say what happens if you try to cast a spell with an improper target but the [RAI is that if the spell doesn't involve an attack roll or an area, the spell doesn't go off](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/822229304729681920)."

This is weird and surprising.  I would have expected that, if a wizard tries to cast a spell with an invalid target, the spell would be lost.

(Side question: if a wizard is worried about mimics, can the wizard attempt to cast magic missile on furniture, knowing the spell will usually not be lost?)

The link above goes to a tweet which goes to another tweet which goes to a WotC page which goes to a 90-minute podcast.  Has anyone got a better source for this answer?

Comment: Also related: [Does magic missile hit silent image's illusory creature?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78016/does-magic-missile-hit-silent-images-illusory-creature)