# Does the Dispel Magic spell work on the Mirror Image spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, illusion

Looking at both [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132996) about how *faerie fire* interacts with *mirror image* and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151542) about whether you can target the illusory duplicates themselves, I saw that both quote this section of [*mirror image*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirror-image):

> A duplicate can be destroyed only by an attack that hits it. It ignores all other damage and effects.

I am now unsure how to interpret this with regards to *dispel magic*, which I would certainly argue *destroys* the illusory duplicates and would consider it to be an effect.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes

*[Dispel Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic)* works by targeting:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

You can target the effect, *mirror image*, or you can target the creature that has it. The specific rules around *dispel magic* allow for targeting of a spell effect when normally you don't (such as the general rules around *mirror image*.)

### You're not targeting a duplicate

Most importantly here, you're not 'targeting' a duplicate, you are targeting the spell effect. That's *any* spell effect, it just happens to be the spell effect of *mirror image*.

Either way, the spell is dispelled.

Comment: I think my main point is that mirror image says they ignore all effects except attacks. So why does dispel magic suddenly work?

Comment: Because *dispel magic* says you can target an effect. And you can target the creature.

Comment: @Medix2 That's how *mirror image* generally works. *Dispel magic* is specific, and different, than any other type of mechanic. And again, you can just target the creature and end it without targeting the effect if that's the concern. It's still a magical effect ongoing on a creature that is dispellable. If it couldn't be dispelled, it'd say so. If you've got a differing answer, post it!

Comment: @Medix2 Because Dispel Magic ends the spell creating the effect. It doesn't do anything to the effect itself so any immunity the effect has is irrelevant. Mirror Image has no stated protection from ending, so Dispel Magic ends it.

Comment: @NautArch I think the problem here is that Mirror image doesn't explicitly say what happens to the duplicates at the end of the duration (which spells normally say), so it implies the duplicates are only destroyed by damage. I think that is the source of the OP's confusion.

Comment: @Tezra Maybe, but the spell duration covers that. I think OP's concern is that typically the only way to 'hit' a duplicate is with an attack roll.

Comment: @NautArch I mean it's not immediately obvious that the spell ending also ends the duplicates. So the OP thinks Dispel Magic is dispeling the duplicates by ending the duration of the duplicates (effect on the duplicate), rather than the parent spell (effect on Mirror Image spell). Just more emphasis on that this is a chain-reaction, and not just direct dispel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96109/discussion-between-nautarch-and-tezra).

Answer (score 11):

I think you're being confused by the difference between the images being destroyed, and the spell ending.  *[Dispel Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic)* doesn't destroy the images, it ends the spell/effect. Similarly, *[Mirror Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirror-image)* has a duration of 1 Minute. After this one minute, the spell ends, and the images wink out of existence, regardless of whether or not they were attacked.

On another note, entering the area of an *[Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)* will suppress the images, but they will wink back into existence upon leaving the area.

Answer (score 6):

### Dispel Magic ends Mirror Image by targeting the creature

Dispel Magic is a spell that can be used targeting a creature, requiring no attack roll:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

Mirror Image does not stop spells that directly target a creature with no attack roll (see [this Q/A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77973/does-mirror-image-affect-spells-that-have-no-attack-roll])). This means that such a spell affects a creature normally.

Therefore, you simply target the creature and the Mirror Image spell ends, (causing the duplicates to vanish because the spell ended). The fact that duplicates "ignores all other damage and effects." does not matter because by using Dispel Magic on the creature you are ending the spell itself, not a duplicate.

Comment: The Q/A you've linked actually says that mirror image wouldn't interact with dispel magic because it doesn't have an attack roll at all. "If a spell doesn't say that the caster makes a spell attack, then mirror image doesn't interact with it"

Comment: @Medix2 Precisely, but you can still target the creature that used mirror image. In the same way Magic Missile just damages the creature, Dispel Magic just ends all spells on the creature. You are not destroying the duplicates, you are ending the spell.

Comment: @Medix2 The duplicates are an effect of the spell. Note the additional sentence "The spell ends when all three duplicates are destroyed." The spell ending and the duplicates being destroyed are not the same thing. They just happen to coincide because the images being destroyed ends the spell and the spell ending means all effects disappear

Answer (score 0):

Dispel Magic can either target "one creature, object, or magical effect." If Dispel Magic targets the creature on which Mirror Image was cast, it doesn't destroy the duplicate, it ends the spell maintaining the duplicate (causing the duplicate to end). The clause in Mirror Image can't apply unless Dispel Magic specifically targets the duplicate. As the former is the more intuitive way to use Dispel Magic in this situation, the latter, more complicated case can be ignored.

Comment: I think you have the right of it but it would be really good to see supporting quotes in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of the answers that imply Dispel Magic does anything other than end a spells duration. I think that is important to notice that Dispel Magic is a non-line-of-sight targeted spell. Mirror Image creates duplicates for 1 minute, that last the duration or till they take damage. Your target is the Mirror Image spell, not one of the duplicates.

Dispel Magic works by reducing the remaining duration of the spell to 0, causing the spell to end just like if the duration normally expired. (So levitate would still do the gentle fall if it's dispelled)

Since Mirror Image duplicates do not persist after the spell ends, the duplicates disappear. THAT is why Dispel Magic works (not because Dispel Magic can "destroy magic on a creature", but because it does exactly as it says. It ends a spell (reduces duration to 0)